# From x_1.0 import y - How to handle imports with version in it?

Tags: python, import

I have an .py file with the Name "Calculate_1.0". If i want to Import it i have to write:

```html
From Calculate_1.0 import calculate
```

But ne number in the Name makes some Problems. I got an Syntax error. How do i manage to get this working?

I know i could simply rename the .py, but it is not mine so i would like to Keep it like that.

Thank you.

Comment: Whoever picked this naming scheme made a really bad decision.

Comment: I would like to make it the right way, but as a beginner i just write my Version number in the files as a string. I think this is also not re right way to do this. How do you manage versions the correct way?

Comment: internally, via your spec, or in a `__init__` file with a variable `__version__` in it, in a setup file... Also, the only real problem in the dot you have. See [pep-0396](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/).

Comment: What do you mean with "spec" ? Is a file Name like "Calculator_1_0" common or a no go?

Comment: *This is a no go*. By *spec*, I mean a documentation. But a common practice is specifying the version inside code, wherever it is. But actually, with an `_` instead of a `.`, the "no go" becomes weaker.

Comment: But inside the Code it is not possible without an __init__ ?

Comment: It is. You can definitely simply define a variable `__version__` inside your working script.

Comment: Okay got i now an i will take a closer look into pep-0396. Thank you very much!